# Python: Change url of web browser using webbrowser-control

Tags: python, webbrowser-control

Ok, I know that if you want to open a particular url using pyton you would run:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("buinvent.com")
```

But what if you want to change it to a different url in the web browser without opening a new window or a new tab in the web browser. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('google.com', new = 0)
```

And the docs says:

> If new is 0, the url is opened in the same browser window if possible.
>   If new is 1, a new browser window is opened if possible. If new is 2,
>   a new browser page (“tab”) is opened if possible

https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html