# i want to open new Link in the same tab in Webbrowser Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-webbrowser

I want to create a script that open links automatically.
But i want the program to open the link in a one page pop up..
i tried to open two links one by one in the same tab, but it always open it in a new Tab in the same Browser.
this is the code:

```
import webbrowser
import time

search = input("Enter URL Here : ")
search1 = input("Enter Other URL Here : ")
min = int(input("Enter Wait Time : "))

webbrowser.open(search)
time.sleep(min)
webbrowser.open(search1, new=0)
```

How can I get the URL to be opened in the same Tab as it should be using new=0?

Comment: Check these links: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58565467/16452840),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40443178/16452840) .

Answer (score 0):

After reading some documentation, the Webbrowser module lacks what you asked for.

**BUT**, seems like Selenium would work for you. I did some research and I ended up in [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/4psxme/overwrite_the_current_url_in_a_browser_with_a_new/). You would need to [install the module plus the driver of the browser you want to use](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html). If you wanna try, this code snippet should work.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

link1="https://www.example.com"
link2="https://www.google.com/"
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link1)
driver.get(link2)
```

Comment: it opens in the same window but in a second tab, but i want to be opened in the same Tab

Comment: @axchraf Sorry I misunderstood your question. That's not possible, the documentation states "If new is 0, the url is opened in the same browser window if possible. If new is 1, a new browser window is opened if possible. If new is 2, a new browser page (“tab”) is opened if possible" https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html

Comment: @axchraf edited the answer to reflect my misunderstanding plus added an alternative using Selenium.

Comment: i'm trying this code now but it show me an error when i put this code: webdriver.Chrome()

this is the msg:
start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: Did you install the driver for chrome? https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/

Comment: that's not possible in webbrowser..
i tried selenium webdriver and it worked from the first try

Comment: @axchraf if Selenium worked for you, you can mark it as an answer.